# Is there a reason why people write everything to the DockerFile instead of a separate shell script?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I somehow don't like the `RUN x && y && z ...` syntax we currently use in DockerFile. As far as I understand I could just run a shell script instead like `RUN xyz.sh` and do the same tasks on my favorite language. Does the latter have any disadvantage?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update:

In additional to the point made by David about the complexity, I believe writing everything to the Dockerfile makes it easier for share (thus creating a survivorship bias for you). Namely on the DockerHub, most of the time, you have a "Dockerfile" tab to quickly get the idea on how the image is built. If the author uses `COPY` and `RUN xyz.sh`, he/she would have to host the script elsewhere or the Dockerfile alone becomes meaningless.

---

`CMD` is executed at runtime, that is when the container is created from the image. `RUN` is a build time instruction. So the question is actually why people run things with `RUN` instead of `CMD` at runtime. (You can of course `COPY script.sh /script.sh` then `RUN bash /script.sh`)

1. If you do things like installing dependencies, it could take a lot of time, in case of scaling up your service, this would make auto-scaling useless because it can't be fast enough to absorb the peak.
2. At build time, `RUN` can be cached, so next time the build will be a lot faster.
3. Because the way docker file system works, creating 10 containers from the same image takes only a few more space than creating 1 container. So you can save disk space by installing packages in the image, while if you install them at runtime, they will all occupy a part of disk space.

Comment: Nothing stops you from COPYing in a shell script and RUNning it, which could be a good hybrid solution (getting the benefits of RUNning commands to build a static image and also having a "plain" shell script).  IME the sorts of shell commands in typical Dockerfiles aren't so complex to require this.

Comment: @DavidMaze +1, I am still learning Docker, and I found only CMD examples of running shell scripts. I did not know you can do it with RUN too. I guess I should fix my example if it is not too later for that.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I fixed the question, now both examples use RUN.

Comment: I can accept this. If I don't want to publish to dockerhub, then it does not matter, otherwise it might be important.

Answer (score 1):

RUN executes commands in a new layer and creates a new image. This happens when you build the image using docker build.

CMD specifies a default command an parameters to be run when a container is launched from the image.

In summary. Run and cmd is not interchangeable, RUN runs when an image is created, CMD when a container is launched.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I fixed the question, now both use RUN.